# Set response headers for nginx post requests

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Nginx post requests seem to be removing my headers, so how can I get the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to stay on post requests?

```
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3567/;

        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "http://localhost:8080";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS";
            add_header "Content-Type" "text/plain";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "content-type,rid,fdi-version";
            add_header "Content-Length" 0;
            return 204;
        }

        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "http://localhost:8080";
    }
```

Right now, it works when the request method is set to OPTIONS but not for POST requests. I would expect there to be the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" on my response, but there is not

Comment: If your upstream also sends this header - there will be 2 headers in the response and the browser will ignore them both.

Answer (score 2):

Is your POST request returning an error response by any chance? If so change

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "http://localhost:8080";
```

to

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "http://localhost:8080" always;
```